# How can I change an html output of wcf service with my own content?

Tags: html, wcf, web-services

I wrote a wcf service that uses BasicHttpBinding with some url and a client using this service.
Users should launch a client application and specify the same url that is specified in server endpoint.

However, if a user inadvertently opens this url in a web browser, he/she sees information on how to retrieve service metadata, which is absolutely useless to them.

What should be done in order for him/her to see, for example a help topic?

Comment: You could configure your web server to check if the user agent is a browser and then redirect to help content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn off the publication of the service's metadata.

You can disable it in the Web.config:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
```

You can find more information on MSDN here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgetenabled.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317.aspx

Of course this will still generate a default landing page if a user manually enters the service's URL in the address bar (e.g.: http://www.examle.com/service.svc). However now it will mention that the metadata is currently disabled.

If you want to customize that page I'd suggest you check out the following thread, it contains a complete code sample on how to set it up:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5778651a-b212-438a-b3e8-f7029775d52a/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have custom help page instead of default one you need to modify `ServiceDebug` behavior:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="...">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpHelpPageUrl="Your custom page url" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
<behaviors>
```

The same properties also exist for HTTPS and in case of some special requirements you can also control their "binding".

Comment: +1 for mentioning httpHelpPageUrl. Though it seems it doesn't automatically redirect to the help Url (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/cac08285-be56-492e-a55a-07bc8145b40c)

Comment: -1 because this never worked they way it is advertised. All comments you find for that httpHelpPageUrl attribute are from people who obviously never tried it. The thread from Christophe ends up with a recommended "solution" that writes html from c# into the stream :(