# WCF service visualisation

Tags: wcf, iis

Hallo Again my question is sample, but I can not find way to accomplish this task. As you all know when service is hosted in IIS it has its default page when one navigates to the .svc file. I want to be able to change layout of this page to implement custom design for it.

Is it possible to achieve it at all? or does any of u have any experience relating this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly then all you need is explained here

[How can I change an html output of wcf service with my own content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229579/how-can-i-change-an-html-output-of-wcf-service-with-my-own-content)

Comment: yes it is what I want to achieve. In Short I want WCF default landing page to be customized and display my own one weather metadata is enabled or not.