# WCF Replace "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled." page with a custom one

Tags: wcf, metadata, publishing, endpoint

I am writing a system where we do not want to expose the metadata on a WCF service. When setting up the service we get our clients to browse the .svc files in order to determine if they have hosted the service correctly.

Where does his page come from, is it an IIS contsruct? Is it generated by WCF?
Is it possible to replace the html page that comes up with our own custom html page?

Answer (score 0):

httpHelpPageUrl lets you move the default WCF help page to another location from serviceDebug element. Make sure you turn off httpGetEnabled.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" 
                    httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" 
                    httpHelpPageEnabled="true" 
                    httpHelpPageUrl="myhelpPage.html" 
                    httpsHelpPageUrl="myhelpPage.html"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

More information [SO How can I change an html output of wcf service with my own content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229579/how-can-i-change-an-html-output-of-wcf-service-with-my-own-content)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. There is an extreme complex solution to this simple problem @ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5778651a-b212-438a-b3e8-f7029775d52a