# .NET Web API - Disable default web page in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to disable the default web page?  Our security specialist does not want the default landing page to appear.  This is using .NET Web API with IIS 8.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom WCF Landing Page when Hosted in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533783/custom-wcf-landing-page-when-hosted-in-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want the default page to exist, you can just delete the controller or change its actions. (*Controllers/HomeController/Index*)

If you dont want to be routed there, change route mapping in `RouteConfig` (it is set there as a default - `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`)

In both those cases you will see error page if you dont change configuration to match.

If you want some specific page to load after you start project in VS, change Project->Properties->Web->Start URL

Maybe read something about routing in ASP.NET. [This looks like starter info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)